# PHP MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument does not make a reflection

Tags: php, mongodb, bson

can somebody explain me please why my PHP code is not able to make a reflection of MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument? There is a line `elseif(is_object($var))` which correctly catch an object but without any properties. Other PHP objects are logged correctly. Also a private and protected values. Why BSONDocument cant?

```
function varLog( $var, $log = 'info', $deph = 2, $round = 0)
{
    $logFile = __DIR__ . '/../log/' . $log . '.log';
    file_put_contents( $logFile, '(' . gettype( $var ) . ') ', FILE_APPEND );

    if( in_array( gettype($var), ['integer', 'double', 'string'] ) )
    {
        file_put_contents( $logFile, $var . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
    }
    elseif( in_array( gettype($var), ['boolean', 'NULL'] ) )
    {
        $var = is_null( $var ) ? 'NULL' : ($var ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE');
        file_put_contents( $logFile, $var . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
    }
    elseif ( is_array( $var ) )
    {
        file_put_contents( $logFile, 'length ' . count($var) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );

        foreach ( $var as $key => $val )
        {
            file_put_contents( $logFile, str_repeat('    ', $round + 1) . $key . ' => ', FILE_APPEND );
            if ( $round + 1 <= $deph )
            {
                varLog( $val, $log, $deph, $round + 1 );
            }
            else
            {
                file_put_contents( $logFile, '(' . gettype( $val ) . ')' . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
            }
        }
    }
    elseif ( is_object( $var ) )
    {
        file_put_contents( $logFile, get_class( $var ) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
        $props = (new ReflectionClass( $var ))->getProperties();
        foreach ( $props as $prop )
        {
            $prop->setAccessible( true );
            $scoope = $prop->isPrivate() ? '(private)' : ($prop->isProtected() ? '(protected)' : '(public)');
            file_put_contents( $logFile, str_repeat('   ', $round + 1) . $scoope . ' ' . $prop->name . ' => ', FILE_APPEND );
            if ( $round + 1 <= $deph )
            {
                varLog( $prop->getValue( $var ), $log, $deph, $round + 1 );
            }
            else
            {
                file_put_contents( $logFile, '(' . gettype( $prop->getValue( $var ) ) . ')' . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the class here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/blob/master/src/Model/BSONDocument.php

It does not have any properties.